# Exchange 2010 replication problems while c# powershell invoking multiple commands

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server-2010

I have a problem with sequentially invoking multiple powershell commands on HA Exchange environment (on single development host everything work fine). As long as it was about only Exchange commands I used workaround by piping multiple commands (execution was on the same node) everything was fine. My code:

```
string casUri = "cas1.srv.net/Powershell?serializationLevel=Full";
string credentialUserName = "User";
string credentialUserPassword = "secret";
string newOU = "thenewou";
string baseOU = "OU=root,DC=srv,DC=net";         
        System.Security.SecureString passwd = new System.Security.SecureString();
        foreach (char c in credentialUserPassword) {
            passwd.AppendChar(c);
        }
        PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(credentialUserName, passwd);

        WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(
                new Uri(casUri),
                "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange",
                credential);

        connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Default;
        runspacePool = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspacePool(1, 5, connectionInfo);
        runspacePool.Open();

        powershell = PowerShell.Create();
        Command command;
            command = new PSCommand();
            command.AddCommand("New-ADOrganizationalUnit");
            command.AddParameter("Path", baseOU);
            command.AddParameter("Name", newOu);
            command.AddParameter("DisplayName", "My new OU");
            powershell.Commands = command;
        powershell.Invoke();

        // ... another AD commands: Set-ADForest, New-AcceptedDomain (work fine)
        // v--- trouble
            command = new PSCommand();
            command.AddCommand("New-GlobalAddressList");
            command.AddParameter("Name", "GAL.Name");
            command.AddParameter("RecipientContainer", newOu + "," baseOU);
            powershell.Commands = command;
        powershell.Invoke();
```

Problem doesn't exists in single host environment.
On HA like this, another commands run on different hosts:

```
   [myApp]---[CAS load balancer]---[CAS-1..CAS-N]---[EX-1..EX-N]
```

This cause an exception:

```
 Active Directory operation failed on DC2.srv.net. This error is not retriable.          
 Additional information: The name reference is invalid.
 This may be caused by replication latency between Active Directory domain controllers.
 Active directory response: 000020B5: AtrErr: DSID-03152804, #1:
            0: 000020B5: DSID-03152804, problem 1005 (CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE), data 0, Att 9b7f0292 (msExchSearchBase)
```

I have no idea how to force persistent connection with single remote shell for few commands. 
Have you got any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this?

```
command.AddParameter("DomainController", "Your Domain Contorller FQDN");
```